# Environmental variables are not loading while running service startup script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

when i start service script with ./script start able to get the credentials through proxy (Environment variables found), if i start the service script like service script start not able to get the credentials through proxy(Environment variables not found), Proxy was not found. How can i work this script through service script start?

script :

```
#!/bin/bash -l
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80

if [ "$system" = "redhat" ]; then
    ## source platform specific external scripts
    . /etc/init.d/functions
  ## set or override platform specific variables
    lockfile=${LOCKFILE-/var/lock/subsys/$SERVICE_NAME}

    ## set or override platform specific functions
    start_daemon() {
        daemon --user $1 --pidfile $2 "$3 $4"
    }
    log_daemon_msg() {
        echo -n $"$1"
    }
    echo_ok() {
        echo_success; echo
    }
    echo_fail() {
        echo_failure; echo
    }
    log_success_msg() {
        success $"$@"
    }
    log_failure_msg() {
        failure $"$@"
        echo $"$@"
    }
    log_action_msg() {
        echo $@
    }
fi

if [ -n "$http_proxy" ] ; then
   echo "proxy found"
    echo $http_proxy | grep "@"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        PROXY_HOST=$(echo $http_proxy | sed 's/http:\/\/.*@\(.*\):.*/\1/')
        PROXY_PORT=$(echo $http_proxy | sed 's/http:\/\/.*@.*:\(.*\)/\1/' | tr -d "/")
        USERNAME=$(echo $http_proxy | sed 's/http:\/\/\(.*\)@.*/\1/'|awk -F: '{print $1}')
        PASSWORD=$(echo $http_proxy | sed 's/http:\/\/\(.*\)@.*/\1/'|awk -F: '{print $2}')
    else
        PROXY_HOST=$(echo $http_proxy | sed 's/http:\/\/\(.*\):.*/\1/')
        PROXY_PORT=$(echo $http_proxy | sed 's/http:\/\/.*:\(.*\)/\1/' | tr -d "/")
    fi
fi

start() {

        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            CMD="java "
            if [ -n "$PROXY_HOST"   -a  -n "$PROXY_PORT" ] ; then
                CMD="java -Dhttps.proxyHost=$PROXY_HOST -Dhttps.proxyPort=$PROXY_PORT"
                if [ -n "$USERNAME" -a -n "$PASSWORD" ]; then
                CMD="$CMD -Dhttps.proxyUser=$USERNAME -Dhttps.proxyPassword=$PASSWORD"
                fi
            fi
            #nohup $CMD -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
            #echo "$PATH_TO_JAR"
            echo "$CMD"
            nohup $CMD -jar $PATH_TO_JAR 2>> /tmp/glog >> /tmp/glog &
            echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME

            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
     }
 case "$1" in
    start)
       start
       ;;
*)
       echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

When i am running this script like ./script start, script able to find proxy settings and passing the proxy settings. But while running with service script start not able to find proxy settings. Did i miss anything to load environment variables while running script with service?

Answer (score 2):

From `man service`:

> service runs a System V init script in as predictable environment as possible, removing most environment variables and with current working directory set to /.

So when you try to run a service script, only several env variables like `TERM`, `LANG` remains, your `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` is discarded. To use environment variables you need, you could define them in file `/etc/default/yourservice` with:

```
http_proxy=http://yourproxy.com
https_proxy=http://yourproxy.com
```

and `source` it in the beginning of your script:

```
[ -f /etc/default/yourservice ] && . /etc/default/yourservice
```